# How do I get the onEdit script to run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've created a spreadsheet then added some values. I opened the script editor through the menu and added an onEdit function. I cannot, for the life of me, get that script to do anything when I edit a cell in the sheet.

It will run if I specifically press the "run" button in the editor, but that sort of defeats the purpose. What am I missing?

in case it matters here is my code

```
function onBugEdit() {
  Browser.msgBox("test");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng   = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var val   = rng.getValues();
  var col   = rng.getColumn();
  var row   = rng.getRow();
  var h_string = '=HYPERLINK("http://example.com?id='+val+'","'+val+'")';
  if(col == 4) { 
    col = "D";
    cell = sheet.getRange(col+row);
    cell.setFormula(h_string);
  }
};
```

The project trigger is set for the onEdit function but again nothing happens when I edit a cell.

Comment: I have also tried an installed script on the onOpen function. I can see the function registered on the project triggers but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling your function `onEdit` not `onBugEdit` ?
Also remember that  "edit" is registered when you exit the cell after editing it.

---

your code could be simplified to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 4) { 
  makeHyperlink(e)
  }
};
function makeHyperlink(e) {

    e.range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("http://example.com?id='+e.value+'","'+e.value+'")');
};
```

Comment: I had the function named onEdit before, but it wasn't working. I cleared out all the settings and renamed it to onEdit, and this time it started working. Not sure what changed, but it is working now.

Comment: Also, it might be better practice to write a separate function called `makeHyperlink` or simmilar, and call that from within the `onEdit`. Also be aware that `onEdit(e)` supplies you with an event object that already contains information about the cell that has been edited, so no need to querry them again. Eg: `e.range` and `e.value`. See [G-Docs documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)

Comment: i've added a suggested simplification

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I'll probably simplify it to that. I was going of a sample bit of code I found online just to get it working first.